# Debugging an ARM (STM32) Microcontroller using Qt Creator

Tags: arm, stm32, development-tools

I have been working with **STM32** series **ARM** microcontrollers on IAR Embedded Workbench for a while. For some reasons, now I need to move my works to **Qt-Creator** (both on Windows and Linux). In IAR EWARM, things are simpler: I've never had to deal with linker scripts or startup files, just open an IAR EWARM project template from ST's Peripheral Library release and with some simple adjustments, it's ready. Anyway, I tried to create a new project for STM32F4 on Qt but I faced with various problems.

Is there anybody that can explain this process clearly, **step-by-step**? With the related makefile, linker script, startup and system files if possible.

*Note: Actually, I have a bunch of specific questions about the issue, but since I think that an explanation of the whole process may be helpful for me as well as other embedded newbies, I decided to ask the question this way.*

Comment: What do you call "Qt environment" ? You mean the use of Qt-Creator ? Or you want your program to run in a Qt application ? Or you mean to run a Qt based program on STM32 ? It is not clear to me..

Comment: I want to compile my C code on Qt-Creator and download it to the mCU. I edited the question.

Comment: I don't think it is such a great idea. It will be lot of pain for a tool that doesn't fit really the need.  Why don't you go for something like [CooCox](http://coocox.org/) or [GNU ARM Eclipse](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/) ?

Comment: Or if you don't like eclipse based IDEs, try [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/). It has a nice Embedded toolchain support.

Comment: @Antoine , Qt is the only option at work for now. But I'll definitely try CodeBlocks at home, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually work with this setup, it works wonderful.

First make sure you use a recent Qt Creator version. I downloaded mine from the website. In some Linux repositories it is outdated and does not support the BareMetal plugin, and/or QBS (which is quite useful).

Requisites:

- Qt Creator (download from QT site)
- ARM GCC (Ubuntu: apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi)
- GDB source archive (download from [archive](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/))
- OpenOCD (Ubuntu: apt-get install openocd)

Versions used: Qt Creator 3.6.0, ARM GCC 4.8.2-14ubuntu1+6, ARM GDB 7.6/7.10 with python support and OpenOCD 0.7.0.

1) Install Qt Creator. Open Help -> About Plugins. Find category Device Support and check BareMetal.

2) Go to Tools -> Options. There are a few settings we need to create and adjust in order to compile for an ARM Cortex controller.

a) Go to "Bare Metal" (last category) - add a debugger of your choice. I personally use OpenOCD. At this point you can set the connection to gdb and it's port, as well as init commands. The standard commands are set for STM32F4xx chips - but I guess you can modify it to work with any ARM Cortex controller.

b) Go to "Devices". Add a new device, choose Bare Metal and the GDB provider you have just created. There is nothing else to setup here.

c) Go to "Build & Run" - tab Debuggers. This has been the most trickiest thing to do.

You need an arm gdb version **with python scripting support**. At the time (about 9 months back when I write this post) the binaries in Ubuntu repo does not have this option. You can save a lot of time/hassle by checking if this has changed.

Nevertheless if you do need to compile GDB with python supporet, here is how to do it. Download GDB from the [download archives](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/). I still use GDB-7.6 which seems to work fine, but for this tutorial I have recompiled it for GDB-7.10.

Extract the source archive. Open in terminal and run "./configure --with-python --target=arm-elf". This sets up the make environment for ARM targets with python scripting enabled. Then run make. This takes a while, depending on your system speed. Unfortunately you may be a bit on your own once the compilation stops because of dependency issues. Don't be afraid - this happened to me on my first try too and I figured it out with a bunch of google searches!
If python fails, make sure to install the python2.x-dev package (check your version no - likely 2.7). Assuming compilation went well, you can find the gdb executable in the main directory.

If you're on Mac, the process will likely be similar. But I am not familiar with OSX.
If you're on Windows, sorry you will need to google a bit on how to do this with Mingw or whatever (honestly I don't know). Or maybe find binaries that have this support enabled.

Once you acquired a gdb executable, call it e.g. "ARM GDB" and set the path to it. I personally don't bother to place it in /usr/bin/, but I guess you could.

This window will throw an error if you use a gdb executable that is not compiled with Python Scripting.

d) Tab "Build & Run" - "Compilers"

Create a new "GCC compiler" and call it "ARM GCC". For path use "/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc". The "ABI" is not really important, I have just set it to arm-unknown-unknown-unknown-32bit.

e) Tab "Build & Run" - "Kits". Add a new kit, I called mine "ARM Bare Metal".
Device type: "Bare Metal"
Device: point to the Device you have created with it's OpenOCD/St link GDB server
Sysroot: leave it empty
Compiler: ARM GCC
Debugger: ARM GDB
Qt Version: None - You obviously cannot run the QT runtime on a Cortex m4!
Cmake tool: unused

Make sure there are no warnings in any of the Build & Run tab

3) Make your make/qmake/QBS project. On left side go to tab "projects" and at left-top add the "ARM Bare Metal" kit. This should work without errors.
Your project may start out with a desktop kit. Replacing usually does not work. In that case add an ARM kit and then remove the desktop one.

4) Start your OpenOcd server. I use a STM32F4 discovery for development, and also off-board programming to my own STM32 boards. For any STM32F40x/STM32F41x targets run:

openocd -f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg

This starts a gdb server at port 3333 and a telnet server (for OpenOCD commands) at 4444. As a shortcut I create a few .sh files in my home directory for a quick startup of a GDB server.

5) Start the debug session. It should program and run!

You can set breakpoints, step through code, even more PC back, watch call stack, variables (locals / watch), and disassembly. I'm really quited please with this, but obviously it lacks a few things like:
1) "Register view". Yes it has one, but that's just the CPU registers. I want register view of my peripherals as well.
2) Download progress or more detailed info about connection state. You need to refer to openocd for this.

edit: I have put up an example project on [this Github repository](https://github.com/nlhans/qt-baremetal).. It contains this post with a few dialog screenshots added, as well as a blinky project for the STM32F4 Discovery board using a QBS project in Qt Creator.

Comment: What exactly do you gain using Qt Creator as a tool chain?

Comment: I think a large share of personal preference. I can appreciate the versatility of Eclipse, but I absolutely cannot stand how slow Java IDE's are. CodeBlocks was mentioned earlier too, I guess there is not much difference. They are both IDE's for C/C++ with GDB debugging. I like QBS build system, but it's not a must. I happen to already use Qt so it's nice to stay within 1 environment for coding.
There are probably much better commercial solutions available, but often not cross platform or out of budget for many hobbyists or small teams.

Comment: I used Qt and Qt Creator for the one desktop application I've ever written, and never in a million years would have thought people were using it for embedded development. Something new every day...

Comment: There are many ways leading to Rome. Any IDE that talks to GDB will be used at some point for cross-platform or embedded development I suppose. Visual Studio can also talk to OpenOCD via the VisualGDB plug-in, and so it can be (is being) used for ARM development. 
OTOH one could also write a script that runs a Makefile and calls a JTAG cmd line tool to upload their binary image to their board. You could use Vim and debug via serial/scope. No need for any interface or debugger that supports code stepping. If that is what works for you that's fine too right? :-)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about the bareMetal plugin.  I remember hearing it mentioned once and then forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [GCC-ARM](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download), [OpenOCD](http://openocd.org) and [ST-Util](https://github.com/texane/stlink). [STM32CubeF4](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF259243) is optional but mandatory.

Add a custom compiler and debugger as image bellow on **Tools->Options->Build & Run**.

[image]

Learn how to use OpenOCD, GDB and ST-Flash.

**Suggested Sites:**

Cover all setup of QtCreator

http://www.bartslinger.com/cx-10-quadcopter/debugging-stm32-from-qtcreator/

Simple bare metal project for STM32 (it's mine)

https://vilacoder.wordpress.com/category/arm/

Answer (score 0):

Good starting point for you is [wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git](http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)

Also you'll find everything you need in their documentation which is on [doc.qt.io](http://doc.qt.io).

You'll get the best support on its official forum [forum.qt.io/category/4/qt-development](http://forum.qt.io/category/4/qt-development).

This is more SO question, and not for SE EE.

Comment: Thank you, I will check these out. 
By the way, I first asked this question on SO and couldn't get an answer for like half an hour, so I decided to ask it here.

Comment: Get STM32Cube to generate a project for eclipse tool SW4STM32 .. you get an eclipse project. 

QT may be able to import this directly, 

or you could look at the makefile it generates in <yourproject>/Your Proj config>/debug/makefile.. You may have to compile it first to get the makefile generated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build Qt targeting STM32, the short  answer is : **Forget it !**

Why ? Qt is meant to run on Windows or Linux as you mention. But is is not possible to run those OS's on a STM32 because it lack a MMU, memory, power, etc..

If you want to port Qt to a new OS or event bare-metal, the road will be very long!

Comment: I don't think the original poster wants to port Qt to a microcontroller. Instead, s/he wants to know how how to get a project running using Qt when starting from scratch. The OP is quite clear about using both Windows and Linux.

Comment: The OP does **not** want Qt on the STM32, they just want to use Qt Creator (the IDE) for STM32 development.